# How can we change status bar color when visitor is on our site Next Js or React JS

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a NextJS app and when user visit my website from there mobile phone I would like to change the app status bar color so that it match my site them

Comment: you can use media query to determine the screen width

Comment: You can use a flag, if the user is signed in from mobile, then set the status of 'active' and based on the status, reflect the same in your laptop/desktop version.